# Is there a way to get the transaction fees on uniswap and sushiswap_

Tags: ethereum, web3js, cryptocurrency, uniswap

I'm building a trading bot and I need to get the cost of the swap transaction on uniswap and sushiswap. But I cant find anything that can help me get it from an API or something similar.

I tried looking at the docs of uniswap and sushiswap but they only talked about how they calculate the fees but not about if there was any way to get them using the SDK or something similar.

Comment: [You can find examples how to estimate trading fees on Uniswap here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.fees.html). Read the function source code to understand the calculations. Note that trading fees (or LP fees) are separate from the blockchain transaction fees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using web3.js, you can estimate the cost in gas units, and then multiply by the gas price, to get the transaction cost in ETH.

Simplified example estimating execution cost of function `foo()`:

```
// how many gas units is the transaction going to cost
const gasUnits = await myContract.methods.foo().estimateGas();

// price (recommended by your node) of each gas unit in wei
const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
```

Docs:

- https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.2/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas
- https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.2/web3-eth.html#getgasprice

Answer (score 0):

you’ll pay the fees when you withdrawal as well, You can calculate your fees at https://buildrmetrics.com

In addition to high gas fees, I see that uniswap or some other exchanges have the following disadvantages:

Uniswap, Susiswap and other decentralized exchanges still utilize Automated Market Makers (AMMs), which can be somewhat disadvantageous for traders. This is because they lack visibility into the prices and are unaware of the actual price slippage.